# logs are not coming after migrating to myBatis

Tags: logging, mybatis

We moved from iBATIS to MyBatis3 in our application.

The only log I am getting in log file is :

> 2016-05-26 12:46:24,973 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.log.MLog] (main:) MLog clients using log4j logging.
>
> 2016-05-26 12:46:25,033 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry] (main:) Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]

My application is a stand alone application under lib folder all jars are there and same is added to class path.
logging related jars are :

- commons-logging-1.1.1
- slf4j-api-1.6.1
- log4j-1.2.16

I suspect mybatis by default taking slf4j for logging so logs are not coming since configuration is done for log4j.

Following is the appender used in log4j.xml

```
<appended name="Mdf345" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="../log/application.log"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%C] (%t:%x)    
                  %m%n"/>
         </layout>
   </appender>
```

Can anybody explains how this works,
because of default mybatis logging other logs supressed ?

Answer (score 0):

Add below logger to your `log4j.xml` and bingo.

```
<Logger name="com.dao.YourMyBatisMapperDao" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
<Logger name="com.ibatis.sqlmaps" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
<Logger name="import java.sql.Statement" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
<Logger name="import java.sql.PreparedStatement" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
```